# Как отнести RGB значение к 7 основным цветам?

Tags: java, color, цвета, rgb, hsb

Мне нужно полученное RGB значение пикселя отнести к 7 основным цветам, каким образом это сделать на Java?

Comment: К каким 7 основным цветам? К цветам радуги чтоли?

Comment: Ну да, представьте себе, когда еще не было компьютеров люди разделяли цвета на семь цветов.

Comment: Ещё в 19 веке, задолго до компьютеров, Джеймс Максвелл разделил цвета на три основных и определил, что этих трёх вполне достаточно :)

Comment: Если сделаете, напишите как решали, внезапно захотелось привести RGB к 9 основным цветам, добавив к спектру радуги ультрафиолетовый и инфракрасный.

Comment: А что делать с черным и белым?

Answer (score 0):

Наверно, как-нибудь вот так можно сделать. Задаете массив цветов, значения которого вам нужны (радуга в данном случае), а потом находите ближайший.

```
public int nearestRainbowColor(int color) {
    int[] rainbow = {
            0xff0000, // каждый
            0xff7f00, // охотник
            0xffff00, // желает
            0x00ff00, // знать
            0x42aaff, // где
            0x0000ff, // сидит
            0x8f00ff  // фазан
    };
    int minDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int nearestColorIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rainbow.length; i++) {
        if (diffBetween(color, rainbow[i]) < minDiff) {
            minDiff = diffBetween(color, rainbow[i]);
            nearestColorIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return rainbow[nearestColorIndex];
}

public static int diffBetween(int c1, int c2) {
    int r1 = c1 / 0x010000;
    int g1 = (c1 % 0x010000) / 0x00100;
    int b1 = c1 % 0x000100;
    int r2 = c2 / 0x010000;
    int g2 = (c2 % 0x010000) / 0x00100;
    int b2 = c2 % 0x000100;
    return Math.abs( r1 - r2 ) + Math.abs( g1 - g2 ) + Math.abs ( b1 - b2 );
}
```

Comment: Только лучше искать расстояния в HSB, а не в RGB.

Comment: конечно лучше найти Hue из HSL/HSB, а потом на глаз расставить углы цветов. Вот кстати [формулы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118528/rgb-to-hsl-conversion). Только черный и белый попадут в красный)))